# How to raise an exception in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, exception

How should an exception be raised in VB.NET?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I don't think there is anything wrong with having a definitive answer to a question like this on this site.

Comment: Sure. But it blows my mind that after the X years this site has been in existence no one has asked this question. As astander mentioned below, it's probably because it is so trivial and easily answered elsewhere.

Comment: I google this question every time I have to write this code.  Glad it's here.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You would throw a new exception.

Have a look at [Throw Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty79csek%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The Throw statement throws an exception that you can handle with
>   structured exception-handling code (Try...Catch...Finally) or
>   unstructured exception-handling code (On Error GoTo). You can use the
>   Throw statement to trap errors within your code because Visual Basic
>   moves up the call stack until it finds the appropriate
>   exception-handling code.

**EDIT**

By request and from the link

```
Throw New System.Exception("An exception has occurred.")
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, understood. If this was a duplicate, then close it as such, if not it should be answered, correct?

Comment: I apologize, and rescind my downvote. How can this question not exist on StackOverflow?!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I think it might actually be that trivial that it might be the lesson after "Hello World". X-)

Comment: I think you might be right. Add an example and I will (still surprised) upvote :-)

Comment: is it possible to manage an exception from the caller function? Ex: Function A call Function B. I force function B to raise an exception but i want to manage it in the try catch of function A.